# How to align items to center in HorizontalGridView?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, leanback

I developed some TV app that has several `HorizontalGridView`, like this one:

[image]

What I want now is, when I have a few items, to be aligned in the center (not in the left, as default). Is there some property, or do I have to use another `RecyclerView`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
fun HorizontalGridView.centerFocusedItem() {
    itemAlignmentOffset = 0
    itemAlignmentOffsetPercent = 50f
    windowAlignment = HorizontalGridView.WINDOW_ALIGN_NO_EDGE
```

}